# SKScene? does not have a member named "Generator"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, skscene

I have added 3 skspritenodes like this:

```
var node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"node1")

func addnode(){

node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"node1")
node.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width/3, frame.size.height/3)
node.size = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width/10, frame.size.height/10)
addChild(node)
node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"node1")
node.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width/5, frame.size.height/5)
node.size = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width/10, frame.size.height/10)
addChild(node)
node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"node1")
node.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width/2, frame.size.height/2)
node.size = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width/10, frame.size.height/10)
addChild(node)
}
```

(I created 25 nodes like this but to explain it easy I made 3 of it)

Now when I remove these nodes with removeAllChildren(), they get removed slowly because they all have the same name so 1 gets removed each.
I want to remove them all in once with a "for" function.

I tried this:

```
let aa = levelnode as SKSpriteNode
    for aa in scene{
        levelnode.removeFromParent
    }
```

But I get this error: SKScene? does not have a member named "Generator"

What is the proper way to delete the nodes with a for-function?

EDIT:

```
override func willMoveFromView(view: SKView) {

 removeAllChildren()

}
```

I tried this with error on following line:

```
override func willMoveFromView(view: SKView) {
    let aa = levelnode as SKSpriteNode
    for levelnode in scene?.children{  // "$T4??" does not have a member named "Generator"
        levelnode.removeFromparent
    }
 removeAllChildren()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give a look to the following Class References :

> SKNode : http://goo.gl/XkWckI
>
> SKSpriteNode : http://goo.gl/XFyUwb
>
> SKScene : http://goo.gl/ZvOMZv

From there two remarks :

- "they all have the same name" : actually, none of them has a name (you didn't set the name property) ;
- "removeAllChildren(), they get removed slowly" : if you've ran this method on the scene it should have worked. But I can't see why it could have been slow, maybe give us the line code you've used (and where) ?

After that, there are several ways to remove node from a scene or another node. What you've tried is partially one of them (you could look for child by name if it was set, etc...). But if we want to stick with what you tried, you are getting an error because you are trying to iterate on the wrong object. Indeed, what you want to do is to loop on the scene children nodes `scene.children`.

With all of that, you might want to give it another try.

I hope it helped. If not, comment with more details.

**Edit :**

With `self` being the scene :

```
self.removeAllChildren()
```

or

```
for node in self.children {
    self.removeChildrenInArray([node])
}
```

It's the same thing.

*My guess about the slowness you're facing is the fact that you call this in the `willMoveFromView:` method. I suppose you're trying to load the same scene, so you might wan't to do that either : remove them before you go to the next scene (i.e. before you use `presentScene`) or remove them after you go to the next scene (i.e. inside `didMoveToView`). But, if you set up properly your scenes at start, you should not even have to do that (or I might have missed something).*